# LeetCode77:Combination. I'm meeting the stack overflow problem when writing a recursive algorithm using Golang

Tags: go, recursion, stack-overflow

LeetCode77:Combination. I'm encountering a stack overflow problem  when writing a recursive algorithm using Golang, even just testing (3,2) at such a small-scale.

This is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func combine1(n int, k int) [][]int {
    res := [][]int{}
    if k == 1 {
        for i := 1; i <= n; i++ {
            res = append(res, []int{i})
        }
        return res
    }
    //The k number contains the combination of digits n
    for _, combination := range combine1(n-1, k-1) {
        combination = append(combination, n)
        res = append(res, combination)
    }
    //The k number does not contain the combination of the number n
    for _, combination := range combine1(n-1, k) {
        res = append(res, combination)
    }
    return res
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("运行")
    
    fmt.Println(combine1(3,2))
}
```

I have checked my code and logic many times, everything seems ok?

Comment: You have a recursive call where you decrement just `n`, but you have no base case for `n <= 1` or `n < k` or similar, so for `k > 1`, you'll get an infinite recursion where `n` gets smaller and smaller until you stack overflow.

Comment: You should be able to do some basic debugging here, either by using a real debugger or simply by adding `fmt.Println("n", n, "k", k)` to the top of your function, and the problem will become immediately obvious.

Comment: yes,you're right. I wrongly thought the stackoverflow problem totally wreck the program, but actually the debugging still work by setting the stop point before the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, after debugging, I found that my algorithm missed the limit of the second recursive part.

```
//The k number does not contain the combination of the number n
if n>k{
    res = append(res, combine(n-1, k)...)//...表示将数组中的元素打散
}
```